# How can I delete a file in FOR loop in batch scripting after another command?

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, ffmpeg

I compress a video with FFMPEG by means of a batch scripting one-liner with a FOR LOOP. After compressing I want to remove the original file.

This code perfectly makes the compressing job, but the original file is not being removed:

```
for %%i in (*.mp4) do ffmpeg -i "%%i" -vcodec libx265 -crf 28 "%%~ni"-small.mp4&&del "%%i"
pause
```

What have I missed?

By the way, this is a near to perfect compression ratio for any kinds of educational videos, tutorials, etc. which have occupied your hard drive.

Comment: Try the DO clause like this: `DO (ffmpeg -i "%%i" -vcodec libx265 -crf 28 "%%~ni-small.mp4" && del "%%i")`

Comment: There are many ways to do this in addition to the way that @Squashman points out.  You can use "enabledelayedexpansion" to allow you to write lines without worrying if they succeded.  I myself prefer "[batch functions](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-functions.html)".  My point?  There are many ways to do things and you might want to use a different method if you need more than a one liner.

Comment: You should improve your way of quotation, change `"%%~ni"-small.mp4` to `"%%~ni-small.mp4"`…

Comment: @Squashman, the parentheses should not make any difference; perhaps `ffmpeg` sets its exit code to a non-zero value, hence `&&` does not execute the following `del` command; for testing I would temporarily use `&` instead of `&&`…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that this methodology will serve you better:

```bsh
@For /F "EOL=? Delims=" %%G In ('Dir /B /A:-D "*.mp4" ^| ^
 "%__AppDir__%findstr.exe" /IR "\.mp4$" ^| ^
 "%__AppDir__%findstr.exe" /IRV "\-small\.mp4$"'
) Do @If Not Exist "%%~nG-small%%~xG" (
    ffmpeg.exe -i "%%G" -vcodec libx265 -crf 28 "%%~nG-small%%~xG"
    If Not ErrorLevel 1 If Exist "%%~nG-small%%~xG" Del /A /F "%%G")
```

The idea is to get a directory listing of all files with an `.mp4` extension. Using the first `findstr` to exclude any files which match the short, *(8.3)*, names. It then pipes those through another `findstr` search, to exclude any of those files which already have `-small` appended to their basename. Next it checks to make sure that there are no existing files within that directory, with the same basename plus the `-small` basename suffix, *(preventing possible overwrites)*. If all of those pass, `ffmpeg.exe` should be invoked, *(subject to `ffmpeg.exe` being in the current directory, within `%PATH%`, or registered as executable with its location in the registry)*. Once the conversion has completed, the script checks the returned `ErrorLevel` was less than `1`, *(to ensure it was successful)*, and if so, whether the new file, *(with the `-small` basename suffix)* exists. If so it will proceed with the deletion, using the `Del` command.

If you wanted to try it again using conditional operators instead of the ErrorLevel, then it would look like this:

```bsh
@For /F "EOL=? Delims=" %%G In ('Dir /B /A:-D "*.mp4" ^| ^
 "%__AppDir__%findstr.exe" /IR "\.mp4$" ^| ^
 "%__AppDir__%findstr.exe" /IRV "\-small\.mp4$"'
) Do @If Not Exist "%%~nG-small%%~xG" (
    ffmpeg.exe -i "%%G" -vcodec libx265 -crf 28 "%%~nG-small%%~xG" && (
        If Exist "%%~nG-small%%~xG" Del /A /F "%%G"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I just put the '/f' after DEL and it perfectly does the job. I don't know if there are any shortcomings of the forced deletion but it works.

A final line:

```
for %%i in (*.mp4) do ffmpeg -i "%%i" -vcodec libx265 -crf 28 "%%~ni"-small.mp4&&del /f "%%i"
pause
```

Comment: Whilst it's good to see that you've solved it, I used the `/F` option with my `Del` command in my provided answer sixteen hours ago! In addition to that I improved your script, and explained to you the methodology it used. Is there a particular reason why you have not accepted it as your preferred solution?

Comment: @Compo I am grateful for your tribute and it's definitely better than my solution. But I wanted just a one-liner which gets the job done with understanding why I can't do without "/F". I indeed didn't pay much attention to your using "/F" because the whlole code is too much difficult for me to understand. I marked your answer as a solution.

Comment: One line code, does not run any quicker, is harder to read, and in your case, is not robust enough for a real world scenario. I haven't, in my code added anything which should not be there, and the second example is a one liner too. I've simply split the long lines for readability.